# Netbeans IDE 7.3 Ubuntu Git

Tags: git, netbeans-7

i tried to checkout one of my repository with NetBeans. But when i click the "Next"-Button i get the Java Waring.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/pkcs11/P11Key

Does anyone have an idea how to fix the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What's your JDK (implementation / version / bits)?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.1) (6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: Try a 32 bits [Oracle JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)